# AngularJs- to filter or not to filter. How to print different html response property inside a loop?

Tags: angularjs

Got some problem that I'm solving now using filters, but I'm sure there must be a clever and simpler way.

Got this **view**:

```
<ul id="FilesView" class="FilesView">
    <li ng-repeat="object in folder.content.object" class="{{object.type}}">
        <img src="object.thumbnails.list | thumbPrinter">
        {{object.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

And a **filter**

```
angular.module('appFilters', []).filter('thumbPrinter', function() {
    if (media.type === 'file') {
        media.src   
    }else{
        '/images/folder.jpg'
    }
});
```

And **XML**

```
<object>
    <type>folder</type>
    <name>Photos</name>
    <complete_path>/Photos</complete_path>
    <complete_path_hash>00e474bd8bd7deaff259</complete_path_hash>
    <date_created>2013-03-06 16:33:28</date_created>
    <date_updated>2013-03-06 16:33:28</date_updated>
    <deleted>false</deleted>
</object>
```

Now this is working. but it is ugly, and has its problems.

Problems like- Lets say that I wish to print img tag, only if I got an img src, and span with folder as bg img. In currect senario I just can't.

How can I **inject HTML** as I wish, **and not only strings**? What is the correct way of doing that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use ng-show or ng-switch to display different chunks of HTML based on a condition?

Edit: Another option is to use a directive that will determine the type of html to be injected.

Comment: Thank you Ketan. What I don't like about ng-show is that it duplicate code and make it very ugly. If I have several options, I'll have them multiplied by loop range. Its ugly.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [ngBindHtml](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize.directive%3angBindHtml). This will prevent the 'unsafe' HTML from being injected. You can also use the [ngBindUnsafeHtml](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angBindHtmlUnsafe), but this will open you to a variety of dangers like script injection, etc.

But from the standpoint of doing things 'the angular way' it is best to do what Ketan suggests.

Keep in mind that ngBindHtml live in a separate .js file.

Comment: Thanks @mfeingold. I'll develop the discussion under Ketan comment. I'll give a look about Bind